# How can I plot specific attributes rather than default of all attributes in Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

How can I plot specific attributes of a time series and not the default of all attributes in the Data Frame. I would like to make a Time Series of a particular attribute and two particular attributes. Is it possible to make a time series graph of headcount and another time series graph of headcount and tables open? Below is the code I have been using, if I try and call specific variables I get error codes. Thanks in advance

```
# Load necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
filename = 'https://library.startlearninglabs.uw.edu/DATASCI410/Datasets/JitteredHeadCount.csv'
headcount_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
headcount_df.describe()

headcount_df.columns

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3)).gca() # define axis
headcount_df.plot(ax = ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of guests')
ax.set_title('Time series of Casino data')
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, I'd really appreciate an up-vote and accepted answer green check. If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to mess around with the ticks and some other formatting, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = 'https://library.startlearninglabs.uw.edu/DATASCI410/Datasets/JitteredHeadCount.csv'
headcount_df = pd.read_csv(filename)

headcount_df['DateFormat'] = pd.to_datetime(headcount_df['DateFormat'].fillna('ffill'))
headcount_df.set_index('DateFormat', inplace=True)
headcount_df.sort_index(inplace=True)

headcount_df_to = headcount_df[['TablesOpen']]
headcount_df_hc_to = headcount_df[['HeadCount', 'TablesOpen']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1,
                         figsize=(12, 8))


headcount_df_to.plot(ax=axes[0], color=['orange'])
headcount_df_hc_to.plot(ax=axes[1], color=['blue', 'orange'])


axes[0].set_xlabel('Date')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Tables Open')
axes[0].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))


axes[1].set_xlabel('Date')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Number of guests and Tables Open')
axes[1].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

fig.suptitle('Time Series of Casino data')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what would you recommend as an approach to get the graph "more spread out so to speak? right now I am having the issue of it just being to dense to gain any information from it

Comment: You're welcome. The headcount_df has 175k rows, so it's going to be hard to see much detail on a single chart. If you want to make trends cleared, I'd recommend using the grouping with the datetime index. https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_group_data_by_time/ Or plotting slices of the larger dataset. Bokeh and Plotly are really nice as well since they allow you to zoom in https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stocks.html, https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/.

Comment: I will look into these. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the green check. Good luck and don't hesitate to post a new specific question if you need a hand.